# i can't upload file and save in database because of characters ( flask )

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, escaping, character

here is my code for upload a file and save into database .. but I have a problem in saving on database because of characters ( like // + : ( etc ... )
please help me to solve this problem, i spent days without a solution
(sorry for my english )
App.py

```
def upload_file():
chemin ='C:/Users/Dell/Desktop/uploads/docmath.txt'
f = open(chemin ,'r', encoding='utf-8')
chaine_de_charactere  =''
contenu = ''
for line in f:
    stripped_line = line.rstrip()
    chaine_de_charactere += stripped_line 
contenu = chaine_de_charactere
f.close()
print(contenu)
LectureDocument(contenu).ajouter_document_dans_la_base()
db.session.commit()
response= construct_response('chaine_de_charactere',contenu)
return response
```

this is my class for reading  document  ..

```
class LectureDocument():
def __init__(self,document_text):
    self.document_text = document_text
    self.adresse_contenu = {} #ou dict()
    self.separateur_debut = "\\n debut \\n"
    self.separateur_contenu = "\\n ad_cont \\n"
    self.separateur_fin ="\\n fin \\n"
    self.separateur_interne_adresse = "_"
    self.document_sous_format_text = ''
    self.id_document = None

def remplire_adresse_contenu(self):
    text_split_sep_fin = self.document_text.split(self.separateur_fin)
    text_split_sep_fin = text_split_sep_fin[:len(text_split_sep_fin )-1]
    for partie in text_split_sep_fin:
        partie_split_sep_deb = partie.replace(self.separateur_debut,"")
        liste_split_sep_con = partie_split_sep_deb.split(self.separateur_contenu)
        adresse , contenu  = liste_split_sep_con
        self.adresse_contenu[adresse]=contenu
    return self.adresse_contenu
```

Comment: You need to post the complete error messages

Comment: the problem is the dictionnary is empty

File "e:\Travail\projet_documents\documents\back_end\app.py", line 467, in upload_file
    LectureDocument(contenu).ajouter_document_dans_la_base()
  File "e:\Travail\projet_documents\documents\back_end\controller\functions.py", line 174, in ajouter_document_dans_la_base
    adresse_initial , contenu_initial = self.adresse_contenu_noeud_racine()
TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable NoneType object